# Online POS terminal?

Tags: credit-card

I need something like physical POS terminal but online, for offline credit card processing without needing CVV code on my site.
Does something like this exists?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does exist. Many bank provide such a service - it is called a Virtual Terminal. PayPal also provides one - https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/virtual-terminal